# altering height of rows produced by grid.arrange when nrow=1

Tags: r, ggplot2

Apologies if this question has already been answered but I cant seem to find what I need.

I have produced two plots in ggplot2 which I am combining into the same grid using grid.arrange as follows:

```
grid.arrange(p1,p2,main="Title", ncol=2)
```

which gives me the plots side by side like so:

[image: Side by side plots]

(Sorry I don't understand how to get this to show my image within the post, if you anyone could help me with that as an aside that would be great! I don't want to annoy people by using links.)

How can I alter this code so that the graphs are still side by side but they are not elongated the entire length of the object? I would like them to be square.

I know that I can add an argument "heights" but not sure if this is what I need and haven't seen anything on here applying it in this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: the most basic solution to this problem is to plot on a "fatter" graphics device window, e.g. `dev.new(width=10, height=5)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also specify relative heights and widths using the `heights` and `widths` arguments to grid.arrange like so:

```
grid.arrange(p1 , p2 , widths = unit(0.5, "npc") , heights=unit(0.5, "npc") , main="Title", ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted thanks :) - I saw this in one of the help pages but it was unclear to me. What does the "npc" stand for?

Comment: @NicolaCook Great! npc = normalised parent coordinates - basically analogous to a proportion of the plot area, so values range from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 4):

As you are using ggplot2 to make plots then one way would be to use `coord_fixed()` to get quadratic plots and then arrange them. You can achieve this with `coord_fixed()` where `ratio=` is calculated by dividing range of `y` values by range of `x` values.

```
ratio.plot1<-abs(max(iris$Petal.Width)-min(iris$Petal.Width))/abs(max(iris$Petal.Length)-min(iris$Petal.Length))

ratio.plot2<-abs(max(iris$Sepal.Width)-min(iris$Sepal.Width))/abs(max(iris$Sepal.Length)-min(iris$Sepal.Length))

p1<-ggplot(iris,aes(Petal.Width,Petal.Length))+geom_point()+
  coord_fixed(ratio=ratio.plot1)
p2<-ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Width,Sepal.Length))+geom_point()+
  coord_fixed(ratio=ratio.plot2)
grid.arrange(p1,p2,main="Title",ncol=2)
```

[image]