# How to decrease space from boxplot to edge with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, r-grid

I want to put a `boxplot` beneath a histogram. I already figured out how to do this, but the `boxplot` and the histogram are equally sized and I want to slim down the `boxplot`.
When I decrease the width, the spaces to the edges stay the same. However, I want to decrease the width of the whole thing.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
library(ggplot2)
h = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(100, 200, 300), limits=c(0,400)) +
  geom_density(, linetype="dotted")

b <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=factor(0),hp))+geom_boxplot(width=0.1) +
  coord_flip(ylim=c(0,400)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(100, 200, 300)) +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y=element_blank())

library(gridExtra)
plots <- list(h, b)
grobs <- list()
widths <- list()
for (i in 1:length(plots)){
  grobs[[i]] <- ggplotGrob(plots[[i]])
  widths[[i]] <- grobs[[i]]$widths[2:5]
}
maxwidth <- do.call(grid::unit.pmax, widths)
for (i in 1:length(grobs)){
  grobs[[i]]$widths[2:5] <- as.list(maxwidth)
}
do.call("grid.arrange", c(grobs, ncol=1))
```

[image: hist+boxplot]

**Edit:**
If I use grid.arrange() like so:

```
grid.arrange(heights=c(4,1), h, b)
```

[image]

The proportions are exactly like I wanted it, but I cannot figure out how to adjust my first example above so that the axes are aligned again.

Anyone?

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148076/altering-height-of-rows-produced-by-grid-arrange-when-nrow-1

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't look like what I'm after. If your're referring to the heights option of grid.arrange, could you please tell me how to adjust my example accordingly. All my tries so far have failed.

Comment: +1 for such a nicely reproducible question with an almost-there attempt included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use your width-corrected grobs, not the original plots, in the `grid.arrange` call.

```
grid.arrange(heights = c(4, 1), grobs[[1]], grobs[[2]])
```