# Side-By-Side ggplots within rMarkdown using grid.arrange()

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, gridextra

I want to display two plots (ggplot) side-by-side in an html report.  Most resources suggest `grid.arrange()` from the package gridExtra is the simplest way to accomplish this.  However, grid.arrange() is changing the proportions of my plots (squishing them along the x-axis).  I want to maintain axis proportions.  I've played with `widths=` and `heights=`  options but nothing has worked.

If this isn't easily resolved with `grid.arrange()`, are there other alternatives for displaying images side-by-side?

P.S. I did see [altering height of rows produced by grid.arrange when nrow=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148076/altering-height-of-rows-produced-by-grid-arrange-when-nrow-1), but the solution did not work for me.

Thanks!

```
{r Images, echo=FALSE}
p1 <- ggplot(pcaData, aes(PC1, PC2, color=By_Experiment, shape=Date)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  xlab(paste0("PC1: ",percentVar[1],"% Variance")) +
  ylab(paste0("PC2: ",percentVar[2],"% Variance")) +
  labs(title="PCA of Gene Counts (rLog Transformed)") +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(color = "black"))

p2 <- ggplot(pcaData, aes(PC1, PC2, color=By_Experiment, shape=Calcium_TP)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  xlab(paste0("PC1: ",percentVar[1],"% Variance")) +
  ylab(paste0("PC2: ",percentVar[2],"% Variance")) +
  labs(title="PCA of Gene Counts (rLog Transformed)") +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(color = "black"))

p1
p2
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```

[image: Expected Proportions]
[image: grid.arrange() output]

Comment: Can you please share the data with same structure as yours to reproduce your problem? Including the output of `dput(pcaData)` in the body of your question is a great way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the dimensions of the plots produced in an HTML report by including `fig.width` and `fig.height` in the beginning of the code chunk. Try to include `{r, fig.width=12, fig.height=4}` and see if the plots looks less squashed.

Comment: Adding this to the code chunk in combination with `grid.arrange()` worked perfectly.  How did you decide on the values for `fig.width` and `fig.height`?

Comment: I literally made two plots and tried out values.