# How to create plots with same widths (excluding legend) with grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created the plot below where the width of two plots is not same because the text length in the legend exceeds in **Plot B**.
[image]

I am using the following code:

```
#Plot A
A<- ggplot(df_a, aes(x=Timestamp, y=Frequency, fill=Topic)) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 month', date_labels = "%b")+
  geom_area(alpha=0.6 , size=1, colour="black", position = position_fill())+
  ggtitle("Plot A")


# Plot B
B<- ggplot(df_b, aes(x=Timestamp, y=Frequency, fill=Topic)) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 month', date_labels = "%b")+
  geom_area(alpha=0.6 , size=1, colour="black", position = position_fill())+
  ggtitle("Plot B")

title=text_grob("", size = 13, face = "bold") #main title of plot
grid.arrange(grobs = list(R,Q), ncol=1, common.legend = TRUE, legend="bottom",
             top = title, widths = unit(0.9, "npc"))
```

I am even using `widths = unit(0.9, "npc")` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148076/altering-height-of-rows-produced-by-grid-arrange-when-nrow-1), but it maintains the width of both plots including legend text. Therefore the actual width of the plots remains unequal.

Can someone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some spacing legend labels of plot A. This will also keep the legend key boxes nicely aligned, and the labels effectively right-justified.

```r
#Plot A
A<- ggplot(df_a, aes(x=Timestamp, y=Frequency, fill=Topic)) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 month', date_labels = "%b")+
  geom_area(alpha=0.6 , size=1, colour="black", position = position_fill())+
  ggtitle("Plot A") +
  theme(legend.spacing.x = unit(6.1, 'mm'))


# Plot B
B<- ggplot(df_b, aes(x=Timestamp, y=Frequency, fill=Topic)) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 month', date_labels = "%b")+
  geom_area(alpha=0.6 , size=1, colour="black", position = position_fill())+
  ggtitle("Plot B")



title=text_grob("", size = 13, face = "bold") #main title of plot
grid.arrange(grobs = list(A, B), ncol=1, common.legend = TRUE, legend="bottom",
             top = title, widths = unit(0.9, "npc"))
```

[image]

---

**Packages and data used**

```r
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

set.seed(1)

df_a <- data.frame(Timestamp = rep(seq(as.Date('2022-01-01'), 
                                       as.Date('2022-12-01'),
                                       by = 'month'), 5),
                   Frequency = runif(60, 0.1, 1),
                   Topic = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 12))

df_b <- data.frame(Timestamp = rep(seq(as.Date('2022-01-01'), 
                                       as.Date('2022-12-01'),
                                       by = 'month'), 5),
                   Frequency = runif(60, 0.1, 1),
                   Topic = rep(c('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE'), each = 12))
```